# find all files matching exact name with and without an extension

Tags: python, glob

I'm using glob to scan a specified directory to find all files matching the specified name, but I can't seem to get it to work with files with no extension without finding files matching the name and then some...

For example, here's some files:
- file
- file2
- file.dat

The resulting list should be:
`[ 'file', 'file.dat' ]`

How can I get glob to work as expected??

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after posting this question, I thought of the answer, but gave up the phone before I could post it...

So instead of relying on glob to find the royal all files, have it only look for files with extensions.

Here's how to validate if glob is even needed:

```
path = 'subdirectory/filename' # no extension

files = [ path ] # for consistancy
if not os.path.exists( path ):
    files = glob('%s.*'%path)
    if not files:
        raise IOError("no files found")

for f in files:
    # do whatever
```

This should work with most names, including weirdly formatted names.

Comment: Can't  Mark it accepted currently, and doubt I'll even look at this in 2 days, so yea, this was my accepted answer before I even posted it.